# How to upload file in node js and get it in an byte array

Tags: upload, multipart

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CF6Hc.png)

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
var fs = require('fs');
const multer  = require('multer')
app.use(express.json());

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
const port = 3000;
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, './uploads')
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, file.originalname)
    }
})
var upload = multer({ storage: storage })
app.use('/uploads', express.static('uploads'));

app.post('/file', upload.single('file'), async function (req, res, next) {

  console.log(JSON.stringify(req.file))
 
  
  const data = req.file.buffer;

var response = '<a href="/">Home</a><br>'
response += "Files uploaded successfully.<br>"
response += `<img src="${req.file.path}" /><br>`
return res.send(response)
  
})
```

Can anyone help me please how to get the file in a variable as a byte array , in spring boot its easy but here in node js i am not able to understand

i am trying to upload it using form-data in postman but im unable to get it in a array , its getting uploaded into the project folder structure .

Answer (score 1):

When initializing multer, add the option that the storage is memory storage.

```
    const multer=require('multer');
    const upload=multer({ storage: multer.memoryStorage() });
    .....
    app.post('/upload', upload.single('uploaded'), (req, res) => {
        if (req.file) {
            //req.file.Buffer is your data...
        }
    });
```

That's all.. Now the file property of the request object has a "Buffer" property that contains the file contents as a byte array.